# Application.OpenUrl(''file://...") won't work on iOS build from Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to open local PDF file located in `SteamingAssets` folded in Unity from iOS app. I've tried different ways, most of them are working on my Mac, but not on the iPad:

```
public void openPDF(string fileName) {
    Application.OpenURL("file://" + Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + fileName);
}
```

What's wrong with OpenURL() method? Am I missing something?

P.S. also tried to add following flags to Info.plist - no success as well.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

**UPDATE #1**

Now the issue is a bit more precise - iOS can't find the file, which is located in `Data/Raw` folder. When you call the method it returns:

```
2018-07-10 12:09:43.220514+0200 MyApp[7327:780708] TIC TCP Conn Failed [9:0x15b54d380]: 1:50 Err(50)
2018-07-10 12:09:43.233098+0200 MyApp[7327:780708] Task <73D63E76-6C43-477C-987E-AED113CC1788>.<0> HTTP load failed (error code: -1009 [1:50])
2018-07-10 12:09:43.233631+0200 MyApp[7327:780924] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1009
```

I've tried to see where the link is pointing too after Unity build - it looks correct:

```
file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/C0219E08-70E8-4917-855F-A01C9C27DFD7/MyApp.app/Data/Raw/pdf.pdf
```

Comment: What happens when you try this without "file://"?

Comment: @Programmer nothing, just Mac starts to argue "There is no application that can open URL ...", also see UPDATE #1